# Postgres version / psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am running macOS Monterey (version 12.6).

- `psql -V` gives me `psql (PostgreSQL) 14.6 (Homebrew)`
- `postgres -V` gives me `postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.6 (Homebrew)`
- when I run `SELECT version();` inside my psql prompt, I get a postgres version of 8:

  `PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.43931`

Question : how can I get postgres version 14 on the psql prompt ? (I need a function that only exists on postgres 9.3 onwards)

Comment: psql -V gives you the psql version, not the database version you are connected to. Connect to a different database cluster and you might get a different version. Depends on what is installed

Comment: To change the version, upgrade the database cluster.

Answer (score 1):

When you run [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) command alone, you're actually running

```bash
psql --port=5432 --host=localhost --username=postgres --dbname=postgres
```

These are default values that depend on your environment variables and local config.

If you have multiple PostgreSQL versions installed and launched, they are likely just running on different ports. Regardless of how you launched them, you can search your processes and ports to see if it lists multiple versions and where they're listening:

```zsh
ps auxwww | grep postgres
sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN
```

Then just point `psql` to the other one

```bash
psql --port=5433 --host=localhost --username=postgres --dbname=postgres
```

Running `psql -V`:

> ```
> -V
> --version
>     Print the psql version and exit.
> ```

shows you the version of your `psql` tool that you probably installed with the new version of PostgreSQL, which you probably did without uninstalling/upgrading the old database, or even switching it off. So you're using the new tool bundled with the new db, but still connect to the old db where you run `SELECT version();`.